# How can I transparently allocate an internal object in Rust?

Tags: rust, allocation, ownership

I am trying to provide a thin abstraction over a database in Rust. Here's a simplified version of the [underlying database API](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.20.0/rusqlite/index.html) as I understand it:

```rust
// Connection to a database
struct Connection {}

impl Connection {
    fn new() -> Connection {
        Connection {}
    }
}

// Prepared SQL statement
struct Statement<'a> {
    conn: &'a Connection,
}

impl Connection {
    // Create a prepared statement
    fn prepare(&self) -> Statement {
        return Statement { conn: self };
    }
}
```

I want to provide a wrapper which upon construction connects to a database and stores some prepared statements. After constructing the wrapper I don't actually need the raw connection any more.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```rust
struct Wrapper<'a> {
    stmt: Statement<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn new() -> Wrapper<'a> {
        let conn = Connection::new();
        Wrapper {
            stmt: conn.prepare(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _w = Wrapper::new();
}
```

`Wrapper::new` fails to compile because the returned value references `conn` whose lifetime ends at the end of the function ("error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `conn`").

The simplest solution is just to require the caller to construct a `Connection`; but then this is a rather leaky "wrapper" for the database.

Ideally I'd like to move `conn` out of the function. Since I'm moving the `Wrapper` out of the function, I thought I could just move `conn` into the `Wrapper`:

```rust
struct Wrapper<'a> {
    conn: Connection,
    stmt: Statement<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn new() -> Wrapper<'a> {
        let conn = Connection {};
        Wrapper {
            stmt: conn.prepare(),
            conn,
        }
    }
}
```

But this just adds another error: "cannot move out of `conn` because it is borrowed", even if I try to dodge the chicken-and-egg initialisation of the `.stmt` and `.conn` fields with `Option` & mutation hackery. I've read that you can't really have one struct member reference another in rust, which would explain this.

For a while I thought I could use an `Rc`, but for this to work I think it would need to be on the `Statement`'s reference to the `Connection`; which is in library code.

Can anyone see which Rust design pattern I'm missing?

Comment: *I don't actually need the raw connection any more* — that's not up for you to decide. The library has decided that it is required, which is expressed in the lifetimes and enforced by the compiler.

Comment: See the "How do I fix it?" section of the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/155423). The primary solution is to use the [rental](https://crates.io/crates/rental) crate, which may or may not work for your case.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes but what I meant was my user code doesn't need a reference - I meant to highlight that I was only trying to keep the `Connection` in the `Wrapper` as a way to control when it gets dropped.